# What is the probability that the difference in the number of successes between two independent tests will exceed a certain value?

Tags: probability

I'm going to ask this question with an example because I'm not certain I know the right terminology.

Suppose I have two coins. I flip the first and increment counter #1 if it comes up heads, and then I flip the second and increment counter #2 if it comes up heads. Then I calculate the absolute difference between counter #1 and counter #2. It it exceeds some threshold, I stop; otherwise, I repeat the process. What is the probability that I will stop for some given number of rounds?

What I think I'm asking: I have two independent discrete binomial random variables, X and Y. What is the probability that |X-Y| exceeds some value at any point during the test, not just at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the variable $Z=X-Y$. $X$ can be $0$ or $1$ with the same probability, just like $Y$. Then the probability distribution of $Z$ is given by

$P(Z=-1)=P(Z=1)=1/4$ and $P(Z=0)=1/2$

This is the same probability distribution we would get if we defined $Z=r_1+r_2$ where $r_1$ and $r_2$ can be $-1/2$ or $1/2$ with probability $1/2$

Now consider the probability distribution of $W_n=\sum_{1\le i\le n} Z_i=\sum_{1\le i\le 2n} r_i$ which represents the difference in the two counters. This probability distribution is the probability distribution of $Z$ convoluted with itself $n-1$ times.

Thinking in the second definition of $W_n$ as $W_n=\sum_{1\le i\le 2n} r_i$, its probability distribution will be  $P(W_n=S)=\frac{(2 n)!}{(n+S)! (n-S)!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2 n}$, as explained [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk1-Dimensional.html).

By the central limit theorem, as $n\rightarrow \infty$ this distribution aproaches a normal distribution with mean $0$.

The variable $|W_n|$ will have the distribution $P(W_n=S)=2 \frac{(2 n)!}{(n+S)! (n-S)!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2 n}$ for $S\neq 0$ and $P(W_n=0)=\frac{(2 n)!}{(n)!^2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2 n}$.
It will have a [Folded Normal Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution), as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

From here, you can compute $P(W_n>k)$ for any threshold $k$ and $n$.

Comment: Actually, the exact distribution of $X-Y$ can be computed exactly in terms of a binomial distribution (see Hoda's answer), and the folding (a little more elaborate since it must be done on both side) can be done for the binomial distribution to get the exact distribution.

Comment: @EinarRodland Thanks, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. One follow up question: if the probability of getting a head is 1/4 instead of 1/2, how does that affect things?

Comment: One more thing that I'm stuck on... If this is all based on a random walk, isn't that saying that the counter can decrease? In my case, I may or may not increment the count, but once I have, I can't decrement it again. So I basically have walkers that either stand still or take a step in one direction. Sorry if I'm just being dense and missing something obvious.

Comment: It's the DIFFERENCE between the counters which can decrease. But you could of course make a random walk in which you only walk in one direction or stay still.

Answer (score 1):

To compliment on @matias morant's answer, the process you are considering is in fact a [one-dimensional random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk) with loop probability $1/2$ and forward and backward probabilities each equal to $1/4$. The walker starts from origin. Then $X-Y$ exceeding some threshold $T$ would be equivalent to the walker's getting farther than $T$ steps from the origin, and you want the probability of (the complement of) this event: "The first time that the walker hits $T$ or $-T$ is more than the test duration".

This connection may help in getting more information on the process, as there is a rich literature on random walks in one-dimension (see e.g. [this paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/EJP-ECP/_ejpecp/include/getdoc39a8.pdf)).

Comment: nice commentary, you are my friend